# For any events $A$ and $B$, prove that $A \cup B = (AB^c)\cup(AB)\cup(A^cB)$.

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, logic

For any events $A$ and $B$, prove that $A \cup B = (AB^c)\cup(AB)\cup(A^cB)$. This result is used to prove that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$ for any events $A$ and $B$.

The result is apparent when one draws a Venn diagram, but how can it be proven mathematically?

EDIT:

I suppose this is a more general form of: if $\omega \in \Omega$, then either $\omega \in A$ or $\omega \in A^c$. Going a step further, $A = AB^c \bigcup AB$ because if $\omega \in A$, it is also either in $B$ or $B^c$ . Are statements such as these obvious, or are they true due to "*insert theorem name here*?"

Comment: By $AB$, do you mean $A\cap B$?

Comment: @Arthur yes, that is correct

Comment: It's the law of the excluded middle from (standard) logic that tells us this: a statement is either true or false, no third alternative:  [tertium non datur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle). So no theorem, just how logic works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

**Adjacency**

$AB \cup AB^C=A$

and you also have:

**Idempotence**

$A \cup A =A$

So:

$AB^C \cup AB \cup A^CB \overset{Idempotence}= AB^C \cup AB \cup AB \cup A^CB \overset{Adjacency \ x \ 2}= A \cup B$

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was looking for, but I wasn't articulating it clearly.

Comment: @tmakino Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in A\bigcup B$ than there are three case:

1. $x\in A $ and not in $B$ , so $x\in AB^c$;
2. $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ , so $x\in AB$;
3. $x\in B$ and not in $A$, so $x\in A^cB$

Then $x\in AB^c\cup AB \cup A^cB$
and so 
$A\bigcup B\subset AB^c\cup AB \cup A^cB$

If $x\in AB^c\cup AB \cup A^cB$ than $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ then $x\in A\bigcup B$ and so you have

$AB^c\cup AB \cup A^cB\subset A\bigcup B $

$P(A\bigcup B)=P (AB^c\cup AB \cup A^cB)= $

$=P(AB^c)+P(AB) +P(A^cB)= $

$=(P(AB^c)+P(AB) )+(P(A^cB)+ P(AB) )-P(AB)=$

$=P(A(B^c\cup B))+P((A^c\cup A)B)-$

$-P(AB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)$

Comment: In the converse on line 6, it appears you used $A = AB^c \bigcup AB$. Is this statement obvious, or is it based on some other result?

Comment: I used the distribution of the cup with respect to the cap :  CD\bigcup CE=C(D\bigcup E)

Comment: @tmakino $A$ is the intersection of $A$ and the "everything"; "everything" is the union of $B$ and its complement. ("Everything" is the outcome set ). Then distribute, as Federico says, $$A~{=A~\cap~(B\cup B^\complement)\\= (A\cap B)~\cup~(A\cap B^\complement)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega$ be the global universe
$$A \cup B = (A\cap \Omega)\cup (B\cap\Omega)$$
 $$ = (A\cap(B\cup B^c))\cup (B\cap(A \cup A^c))$$
 $$ = [(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)]\cup [(B\cap A) \cup (A^c\cap B)]$$
$$ = (A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap B) \cup (A^c\cap B) $$ 
$$\space because \space A\cap B=B\cap A\space and \space (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B)=A\cap B$$